# Using belt drive in LEO spacecraft?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, design, mechanisms

I am designing a concept for a LEO spacecraft and need to transmit mechanical power (0.5Nm @200rpm rotation) over a distance (1-2ft). Chains or belts would be a natural choice for terrestrial applications, however for chains I am not sure how maintenance free they are and for belts I am not sure whether the materials (neoprene with fiberglass and nylon coating) would last. No UV radiation, application inside 1-3mm aluminum housing.

Is anyone aware of an application of a belt drive and the used materials?

What would be the limitations of a chain in such an application?

Comment: how much torque to be transmitted? What rpm?

Comment: I am only familiar with mechanical systems on shuttle; they would use a torque tube, not a belt or chain. Example: https://i.imgur.com/xYC8QV2.png from https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/383449main_mechanical_systems_workbook_21002.pdf

Comment: If uncolored transparent nylon would be exposed to the very intensive UV  light of LEO, it would become brittle very soon. Cable binders exposed to sunlight on Earth are brittle very soon, that is why they should be black for outdoor aplications.

Comment: Uwe makes a very good point! Can you specify the following; degree of exposure to sunlight including UV, to other forms of ionizing radiation, high temperature excursions, low temperature excursions, atomic oxygen in LEO, vacuum or pressurized, is [outgassing of your materials okay or will it cause problems to other components (e.g. optics!)](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/57828/12102) See also [What is the "space grease" used to lubricate the ISS robotic arm? What are the material considerations for it?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/39520/12102)

Comment: and [Why are some reaction wheels sealed with low pressure gas, others with vacuum?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18924/12102)

Comment: Assuming the belts would be composed of a type of "rubber", [outgassing (off gassing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outgassing) might be a problem for the longer term stability of the belt.

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful comments, it shows that for belts it is mainly a materials and fatigue/longevity/brittleness question. So would be interesting to see if someone has done it. For chains i realized that they are probably heavier than using a geared solution with a shaft.

Comment: Metal belts made of spring steel ribbon also exist.

Comment: Since you are considering belts and chains, I assume the power transmission is between parallel non-coaxial shafts. Gears are another option which avoids the materials problem of belts and the lubrication problems of chains. Involute profile gears have only rolling contact, not sliding. It would help if you could post more details, particularly a drawing.